# JdbcTemplate auto wiring only works from the main class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

Im new to spring and Jdbc, JdbcTemplate works when I auto wire it in the main class, but when I auto wire it in any other class it is null.

note: I comment out one of the JdbcTemplate when I test the other, I thought it might make a conflict.

Test class (Main)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  // this works

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("main class jdbc template = "+jdbcTemplate);

    }
}
```

StudentDaoImpl class

```
    public class StudentDaoImpl {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; //this is null

}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

I really have no clue why is this happening, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Spring injects beans to other beans, not to arbitrary classes. Is StudentDaoImpl a spring-managed bean?

Comment: @Lesiak not its not, how can i do it?

Comment: i think i need to add some annotations, but i don't know which one and where?

Comment: Not only you need to add one of spring annotations (`@Repository` looks good in your case) but also let Spring create it, and retrieeve it from Spring's context (or, preferably, inject it to another Spring-managed bean)

Comment: what do you mean by let spring create it?

Comment: You may want to read a good tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dependency-injection

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating the `StudentDaoImpl` class yourself?

`StudentDaoImpl dao = new StudentDaoImpl()`?

If not, then annotate your `StudentDaoImpl` class with `@Repository` so it will be automatically picked up by Springs component scanning.

If yes then you have to set the `JdbcTemplate` yourself (in this case via a setter)

Note: Autowiring doesn’t work when you create an instance yourselves with the `new` keyword.

Comment: yes im creating StudentDaoImpl in main class, and i tried to set JdbcTemplate it still is null

Comment: @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

Comment: you mean this right?  ^^^

Comment: Do you create StudentDaoImp with new StudentDaoImpl(); ?